# Simple html form in Django

Tags: html, css, django, forms

Could you please help me, I don't understand why html+css don't work as expected in Django.

I use a simple form to upload two files, but it looks really ugly.

[image: Without id from css]

**index.html** without `id="upload_container"`

```html
<div class="page_thirdblock thirdblock">
 <div class="thirdblock__container _container">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload1"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="upload_file">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="form_1">
    <button type="submit">Upload File 1</button>
  </form>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload2">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="upload_file">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="form_2">
    <button type="submit">Upload File 2</button>
   </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image: With id from css]

**index.html** with `id="upload_container"`

```html
<div class="page_thirdblock thirdblock">
 <div class="thirdblock__container _container">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload1" id="upload_container"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="upload_file">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="form_1">
    <button type="submit">Upload File 1</button>
  </form>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload2" id="upload_container">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="upload_file">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="form_2">
    <button type="submit">Upload File 2</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

How I can fix it? I mean get `Browse...` button, but with css style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, see what happens

```
<div class="page_thirdblock thirdblock">
  <div class="thirdblock__container _container">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload1" id="upload_container">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label for="file1" class="file-upload-label">
        <input type="file" name="upload_file" id="file1" style="display:none;">
        Upload File 1
      </label>
      <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="form_1">
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload2">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label for="file2" class="file-upload-label">
        <input type="file" name="upload_file" id="file2" style="display:none;">
        Upload File 2
      </label>
      <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="form_2">
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @john deere. Thanks, now better, but fixed form only for ```Upload File 1```

Comment: I fixed for ```Upload File 2```. Thank you!